# add various new columns to a CSV file using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV file. For example columns:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```

I need to restructure it as

```
col1, col2, new_col1, col3, new_col2, col4, new_col3, col5.
```

The values in the rows will be null. I am assuming this has to be done with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk).

I tried the questions already in StackOverflow, but all I am getting is to add at the end or beginning. I need to be able to specify column number/position where the column name needs to be added.

Comment: Please show the current attempt to see where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: awk is perfect for this! `$1` contains the 1st column, `$2`, the 2nd and so on. Good luck and update your question when you're stuck and need additional help

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear since you state: _ need to be able to specify column number/position where the column name needs to be added._ Does this mean that you want to process headers also?

Answer (score 2):

***remark:** This answer assumes that no CSV field entry has <double-quoted> strings (`"string"`) with embedded <comma>- or <newline>-characters*.

If the above is not applicable to you problem, other approaches are needed. Useful links:

- [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)
- [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file?rq=1)
- [Adding a new column to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052462/adding-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file?rq=1) (Python)
- [Insert column to a CSV file in Perl using Text::CSV_XS module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863091/insert-column-to-a-csv-file-in-perl-using-textcsv-xs-module) (Perl)

---

If you want to add a column to a CSV file, you can do the following:

**add a column at the beginning:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print new_value OFS $0}' file
```

**add a column at the end:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $0 OFS new_value}' file
```

**add a column before column `n`:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$n=new_value OFS $n}1' file
```

**add column after column `n`:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$n=$n OFS new_value}1' file
```

**add a column before each of column `n1` < `n2` < ... < `nm`:** (start at the back)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; split("n1,n2,n3,...,nm",a)}
     {for(i=m;i>0;--i) $(a[i])=new_value OFS $(a[i])}1' file
```

or for different values

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; split("n1,n2,n3,...,nm",a); split("value1,value2,...,valuem",v)}
     {for(i=m;i>0;--i) $(a[i])=v[i] OFS $(a[i])}1' file
```

**add a column after each of column `n1` < `n2` < ... < `nm`:** (start at the back)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; split("n1,n2,n3,...,nm",a)}
     {for(i=m;i>0;--i) $(a[i])=$(a[i]) OFS new_value}1' file
```

or for different values

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; split("n1,n2,n3,...,nm",a); split("value1,value2,...,valuem",v)}
     {for(i=m;i>0;--i) $(a[i])=$(a[i]) OFS v[i]}1' file
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you're really enabling  "please give me tips and/or sample code", aren't you ;-> ? Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter maybe true. If the question is interesting, I don't mind helping people out as I think it helps other people. Nonetheless, I will always put the obligatory message to make clear that this is not the way to go forward in the hope their next question might be more upto standards.

Comment: I hope it's obvious I don't really care, as there doesn't seem to be any cure for early posters inability to read and absorb the ?? number of pages attached to `[help]` ;-) .Eventually, you may be get tired of such questions, if not, you're a better person than I am ;-) .And again, a really perfect answer to this problem. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's say your csv looks like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Then, the command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $1,$2,"new_Col1",$3,"new_Col2",$4,"new_Col5",$5}' t.csv
```

will give the following output:

```
col1, col2,new_Col1, col3,new_Col2, col4,new_Col5, col5
1, 2,new_Col1, 3,new_Col2, 4,new_Col5, 5
```

You get the idea? Is that what you want to know?

Even easier to read:

```
awk '{print $1","$2",new_Col1,"$3",new_Col2,"$4",new_Col5,"$5}' t.csv
```